# Validate base64 in python

Tags: python, base64

I would like to check wether a string is base64 encoded in python. As the built in module is very forgiving, I tried the following

```
s = b'111='
b64encode(b64decode(s)) == s
```

To my surprise it returned `False`. Indeed, `b64encode(b64decode(s))` returns `b'110='`. I expected it to return `True` as I'm under the impression `'111='` is a valid base64 string.

My python version is 3.6.4

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

Why is this? Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Since "0" and "1" both only differ in the last 4 bits (and the encoding has 4 padding bits), both are valid encodings of the plaintext. `b64encode()`, however, will only encode using "0" there.

In order to be robust you will need to calculate how many padding bits and bytes the encoded text *should* have and then only compare the significant bytes and bits.